# Create custom IAM policy to hide S3 objects based on a catalog hosted in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have an S3 bucket containing objects and I have a catalog in DynamoDB where I have information about the S3 objects such as

- id (the primary key) corresponding to the object path in the S3
- creation date,
- extension,
  and several others.

I want to create an IAM policy to allow someone to ONLY see the S3 objects where the extension field in DynamoDB is .json.

I have not seen anything in the documentation :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Is the extension not part of the object in S3's name? Or could it not be added as a tag to the S3 object?

Comment: Hello, the extension is part of the S3 yes, but extension was just an example, the idea is to enable granular access based on DynamoDB with other fields (like file_creator, creation_date...)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to have a bucket dedicated to the files on S3 and limit the users visibility to that bucket.

If you remove an item from DynamoDB,you would also remove the item from S3 or change it's bucket.

IAM cannot read DynamoDB so you cannot have a policy determined by your items unless you build a complete custom authorisation mechanism.

Comment: Ah it is sad to see that DynamoDB can not be read by IAM.